# What is best practice to config when changing host in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I develop my Wordpress site from the localhost, name: http://moingaytoisong.dev
My real website is : http://moingaytoisong.com
Every time I pull the database from the live site to my local site, I need to search and change the url in wp_options table. It's quite frustrate.
Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Thank Karan for helping me to edit my question!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your wp-config.php, just need to add these lines below:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://moingaytoisong.dev');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://moingaytoisong.dev');
```

It will overwrite the url in database, so no need to change the url in wp_options anymore.
Your local website and your live website can use the same database without any issue

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check some plugins. You can use **wp-migrate-db** to migrate your database according to your host. You can use **Duplicator** plugin to shift your site from one host to another in a few simple clicks.

For **Duplicator** check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdP3quWLM0Q